# Draw over screen with Quartz

Tags: cocoa, macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to work out what the best way to draw over the top of all other items on the screen on OS X. I don't want to impede the user's ability to interact with their applications, but want to 'annotate' them. I want to be able to draw up to 20 different annotations. The top half of this screenshot from Gizmodo happens to nicely show the *kind* of thing I want to do. http://gizmodo.com/assets/resources/2006/07/04%20Safari.jpg (sorry, I'm too new to post it as an image)

The questions I *think* I need to answer are:

1. Should I create a single window for
   each drawing and draw to that? If
   so, how do I minimise overhead?
2. What kind of window or other context should I use given that I don't want any window
   decoration?

I don't think I want the overhead of creating 20 windows, but I also don't know that I want to create a full-screen, invisible window that contains my context (I presume a subclassed NSView), because I fear that will a) cause problems interacting with what's below and b) break the niceties of only redrawing when necessary (my actual drawing will likely only cover 10% of the screen)

I've not worked with Quartz2d before, so I just can't get my head around how to get the 'right' context to draw on from the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Who

Answer (score 1):

You can only draw into a window. You can make a transparent, borderless window but it will need to be at the front.

You could set it's level to something like `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel` to make it draw above other windows (this will be very annoying to users) but clicking on it will:

a) activate and bring to the front your app

b) Prevent the app underneath receiving mouse events

Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't think so, thanks, due to the annoyances you state! It seems like the most appropriate thing to do is just to create a window for each item on the screen from an application that doesn't have a menu bar, etc... Some Apple Apps seem to do this, so it can't be such a terrible idea :P