# Drawing over screen in Java

Tags: java, drawing, system

I want to create an helper application in Java.. which behaves like: whenever called through a global shortcut, it can draw some text on the screen (not onto its own application window, but on top of the screen).

A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081204/draw-over-screen-with-quartz), but I want to achieve this in Java.

When I search something like "java draw over screen", I can only get lots of tutorials about Java2D.

I want to check: 1) is it possible to draw over other applications in Java? 2) If not possible, is there any alternatives in Mac / Ubuntu?

Thanks a lot.

(Side note: I know java don't have the global shortcut support. I'm trying other methods to solve that problem, non-related here)

Comment: Not going to work. Maybe with platform dependent JNI. But no pure Java way; that's for sure.

Comment: Just for people who stumble across Martijn's comment: It is wrong and already has been wrong at the time of writing (2014). Scroll down to Holger's answer, which worked back then and is still the way to go in 2023 with Java 8u261.

Comment: In regards to the side note at the end of the original post: You can use the library [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to fire events on clicks and key strokes while not having focus on your overlay, so you can still use the underlying software without consuming the click event.

Answer (score 20):

Simply lay a transparent Window over the screen and draw onto it. Transparent Windows even support click-through so the effect is like if you were drawing over the screen directly.

Using Java 7:

```
Window w=new Window(null)
{
  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    final Font font = getFont().deriveFont(48f);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    final String message = "Hello";
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString(message,
      (getWidth()-metrics.stringWidth(message))/2,
      (getHeight()-metrics.getHeight())/2);
  }
  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g)
  {
    paint(g);
  }
};
w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
w.setVisible(true);
```

---

If per-pixel translucency is not supported or does not provide the click-through behavior on your system, you can try per-pixel transparency by setting a Window `Shape` instead:

```
Window w=new Window(null)
{
  Shape shape;
  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    Graphics2D g2d = ((Graphics2D)g);
    if(shape==null)
    {
      Font f=getFont().deriveFont(48f);
      FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(f);
      final String message = "Hello";
      shape=f.createGlyphVector(g2d.getFontRenderContext(), message)
        .getOutline(
            (getWidth()-metrics.stringWidth(message))/2,
            (getHeight()-metrics.getHeight())/2);
      // Java6: com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);
      setShape(shape);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fill(shape.getBounds());
  }
  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g)
  {
    paint(g);
  }
};
w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
w.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thx for reply :) I don't have Java7 installed yet.. when I tried with Java6, I have a totally black background. Anyway to set transparent background for Java 6?

Comment: @Holger Can you please point out for me what this make transparent? i know that it works bud no idea why it behave transparent.How is this *window* different form something like JFrame?

Comment: Starting with [Java SE 6 Update 10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#6u10) you can use `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(w, false)`. Just call it right before `setVisible(true);`

Comment: @Tomas Bisciak: It’s not the `Window` which makes the difference. `w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));` installs a background color with an alpha channel value of `0`. It would work with a `Frame` too if you say `setUndecorated(true)` before making it transparent. But I use a `Window` here so it doesn’t show up in the task bar.

Comment: Oh now i understand.I asked becaose i never seen this approach before.Thx for answer.

Comment: @Holger I've installed java7 and runned your code. Just to check.. which platform you're running it on, and does it support click-through? I'm running on Ubuntu but it doesn't seem to support click-through

Comment: @songyy: I used Windows.

Comment: @songyy: If click-through via alpha doesn’t work for your system you can try `Window.setShape()` to reduce the clickable area. You can use `Font.createGlyphVector(…).getOutline()` to get a `Shape` that matches your text.

Comment: I've just tried to use the Java 9 early access release from Oracle: 
JDK9 Build b51  -- and unfortunately.. The click-through transparency still doesn't work on Mac. Sigh.