# How would I change color of entire screen in java?

Tags: java

I'm looking to write a program that can invert the colors of the entire screen, including the taskbar and everything.

I've tried searching for someone with a similar problem but the results are usually telling me how to change colors in JFrame.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604762/drawing-over-screen-in-java to get an idea.